# Wacom Bamboo crashes gnome-shell on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on tablet button press, proximity

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, tablet, wacom

I have extremely annoying problem with my Wacom Bamboo tablet. It may be that everything works as intended, so perhaps it is not visible to some users of Wacom tablets.

I use Ubuntu 20.04 on Raspberry Pi 4, 4 GB, "desktopified" using Desktopify, dual monitor setup. I suspect none of these specific has a bearing on my problem though. If someone thinks it has, I can test it out under livebooted Ubuntu on my otherwise windows machine (I don't have ubuntu installed anywhere else right now).

**What happens is**, that when the stylus is **brought closer to the pad after it has been lifted** this causes 3-5 second blanking of both monitors (cursor is visible on black background) and corresponding freeze in desktop activity.

It seems like the "discovery" of the stylus proximity by the tablet causes some kind of X/desktop restart.

**If I keep stylus close to the pad at all times** even without drawing/pushing, this does not happen. It strictly happens after the following sequence of events:

1. the stylus is lifted (tablet loses contact, and cursor stops tracking the tablet which is **expected behavior**) (everything ok)
2. the stylus is brought back into the vicinity of the tablet - cursor starts tracking the tablet, but the displays go through aforementioned blink-black-blink-normal phase, and desktop apps are unresponsive for those few seconds (so if drawing anything the shape would be lost for that amount of time).

Any ideas why this happens? The problem is I use OpenBoard app for drawing (actually my daughter is) and this happens whenever the stylus is lifted to go to the pheripheral part of the screen to change tool or color.

So perhaps with some training and **very strong will** not to lift the stylus more than 5mm of the board this could be controlled, that's why I suspect that perhaps is happening to other users -just that everyone else accepts it as a matter of fact?

I am prepare to record videos or generate some logs, it you only give me an idea what logs are needed. I am pretty experienced Linux user/administrator, but this simply baffles me as nobody yet described this phenomenon.

**EDIT:** After playing with it for several hours I found out the following:

1. The "blanking" symptoms are `gnome-shell` crashing. I can reproduce exactly same behavior by simply doing `sudo kilall gnome-shell`
2. Aforementioned behavior/crash happens if I press any of the tablet buttons as well. I was not aware of that since I did not use them before. So not only proximity event is an issue, every press of the tablet button crashes `gnome-shell`
3. My exact tablet model is `056a:0065 Wacom Co., Ltd MTE-450 [Bamboo]`, otherwise fully supported in `libwacom`
4. Knowing all this, it seems that my problem is simply "Why does `gnome-shell` crash when using Wacom Bamboo tablet"

It might be related to the following bug report:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3163

The "fix" it refers to is 5 years old, I think it is not related, it must be a new bug.

Answer (score 1):

After few days, I found the workaround. The facts are as follows:

- The bug lies in x11 backend, which somehow does not properly handle wacom tablet events
- This crashes `gnome-shell`
- The bug has been reported, but it seems there is no activity aimed to fix it

The workaround is simply to change display backend from **x11** to **Wayland**. As soon as I did that, the crashes stopped. Be aware though that this may bring other issues, as Wayland is apparently still not a perfect replacement.

Exact methods how to replace x11 with Wayland in Ubuntu vary, so it is best to find a tutorial that works for you. At the end, the final check whether you are using Wayland or x11 is to print out the following variable:

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

Comment: I recently found my Wacom Intuous works on Wayland on Ubuntu 23.10 but crashes under Xournal++ use on X Windows.